# Can you change view controllers without segue?

Tags: swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, segue

Basically i have a button that changes title, and if the button title is something i want the button to take the user to somewhere different to if the button title was something else

```
let act1 = act1ViewController()
let act2 = act2ViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.buttonName.setTitle(self.text, for: .normal)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

   if text == "cheer up" {
    self.present(act1, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
   else if text == "yay" {
    self.present(act2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the ViewController depending on the if check, and present it:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let destinationVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifier") as! NewViewController
present(destinationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Just remember to set the Identificator in the Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 controllers that you want to show are,

```
class Act1ViewController: UIViewController {
    //your code...
}

class Act2ViewController: UIViewController {
    //your code...
}
```

You simply need to put a **switch-case** on `buttonName's` `title` and present the relevant controller `act1` or `act2`. Create `act1` and `act2` using the `storyboard`.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.titleLabel?.text {
    case "cheer up":
        if let act1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Act1ViewController") as? Act1ViewController {
            self.present(act1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    case "yay":
        if let act2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Act2ViewController") as? Act2ViewController {
            self.present(act2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

}

Don't forget to set `Act1ViewController` and `Act2ViewController` as `storyboardID` of the respective controllers in the `storyboard`.

Comment: i think my let act1 = act1ViewController()
let act2 = act2ViewController()is the issue when i try and run your code ... how do i fix it ??